# Am I allowed to submit to a journal, a paper that was accepted to a conference but not presented yet?

Tags: publications, conference

I am writing a paper in game theory. It is almost ready and I would like to submit it to an economics journal. Meanwhile, I would like to present a part of it in a computer science conference which is also interested in game theory. This will probably not be a problem from the journal's point of view, since the journal version contains much more results than the conference version. It is common to send to a journal, an extended version of a conference paper. But, I am not sure if it is allowed from the conference's point of view.   In the "multiple submission" policies of two conferences, I found a similar statement:

- [AAMAS](http://sis.smu.edu.sg/aamas2016?itemid=10171):  "Authors may not submit any paper to AAMAS hat has already appeared in an archival forum. Authors must ensure that no submission to AAMAS s under review for another archival forum **between the AAMAS submission and decision dates**."
- [IJCAI](http://ijcai-16.org/call_for_papers.html):  "IJCAI will not accept any paper that, at the time of submission, is under review for or has already been published, or accepted for publication, in a journal or another venue with formally published proceedings... Authors are also required not to submit their papers to venues with formal publication **during IJCAI-16 review period**".

I understand that I am not allowed to submit to the journal BEFORE the submission deadline, and not allowed to submit BETWEEN the submission deadline and the acceptance/rejection decision. What I don't understand is: am I allowed to submit to a journal AFTER the decision (assuming it will be an "accept" decision) but BEFORE the conference itself?

The rules do not say explicitly that it is forbidden, but, I thought that it may be "obvious" that it is forbidden, since the conference organizers want to make sure that the paper is fresh and new when it is presented in the conference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're planning to submit the journal paper **after** receiving the decision from the conference. In that case, if the journal is ok with considering an extended version of a conference paper, the conference organizers are probably not in a position to say anything against that. However, you have to follow the standard referencing rules when finalizing the journal paper:

- The material that already appeared in the conference is not "new" for the journal paper, but has been published previously in the conference paper. Accordingly, the relevant section in the journal paper should be formulated as a review of existing results.
- You must cite the conference paper from that section.

Comment: So if I submit to a journal after the decision date, and it is published in the journal before the conference date, the conference organizers don't care that the presented paper has already been published?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Is this realistic to happen in your case? Usually journal publishing is much slower than conference publishing.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: Typically, at some point *before* the conference takes place, you will have to sign a copyright transfer agreement for the conference organizers. You will also have to sign a copyright transfer agreement for the journal at some point before the journal appears. This could put you into the inconvenient situation that in whichever of these you sign second, you agree to transfer exclusive rights to a publisher that you had already transferred to another publisher in the other agreement. The key here is making your journal version an *extended version* of the conference paper.

Comment: See also http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54433/will-i-be-regarded-as-academic-dishonest-if-i-submit-one-paper-to-a-conference-a

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, the journal version is an extended version of the conference paper. Does this mean that I can sign both copyright agreements with no problems?