# How to treat a paper accepted at a conference and included in proceedings if I could not attend the conference?

Tags: publications, conference

Recently I had submitted a paper to a conference. It got accepted for presentation. But I could not attend the conference. However, I had registered for it and paid my participation fee. My paper has also been included in the conference proceeding.

My question is how will I treat this paper:

- Can I include it as a conference paper in my CV?
- Can I submit it to another conference?
- Can I submit it to a journal for publication?

I understand that part of this question is highlighted in previous questions e.g. [Am I allowed to submit to a journal, a paper that was accepted to a conference but not presented yet?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57987/am-i-allowed-to-submit-to-a-journal-a-paper-that-was-accepted-to-a-conference-b), but I need a specific and straight forward answer.

Comment: If you want a clear answer, you need to communicate with the conference organizers. At this point, it's possible that the paper will be retracted from the proceedings (then it counts as unpublished) or will remain in the proceedings (then it counts as published).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's published in the conference proceedings, it's published.

- You can list it as a conference publication in your CV.
- You can't publish it again in conference proceedings.
- Regarding publishing it (or an extended version) in a journal, see [Under what circumstances can one republish a conference paper/presentation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/under-what-circumstances-can-one-republish-a-conference-paper-presentation) especially [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/2674/11365).

Comment: "If it's published in the conference proceedings, it's published." In case of an electronic publication, the editors might still retract the publication.